# Referencing "coupled" tables 

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats

How can I refer to 'coupled' tables (say different tables but referenced as table 5a and table 5b). If I `\label` them and use `\ref`, they would be referenced in the document as *table 5* and *table 6*.

Comment: Have a look at the package `subcaption` or `subfig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete example using the packages [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) and [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) (the latter for automatic formatting of cross-references).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionSubType*{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon}
\renewcommand*{\thesubtable}{\thetable(\alph{subtable})}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{subtable}{subtable}{subtables}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
(Tabular material)
\subcaption{A subtable}\label{tab:foox}
\end{subtable}

\vspace{\floatsep}

\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
(Tabular material)
\subcaption{A subtable}\label{tab:fooy}
\end{subtable}
\caption{A table}\label{tab:foo}
\end{table}

See \cref{tab:foo} and especially \cref{tab:foox,tab:fooy}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My requirement is a bit different though, rather than side-by-side, is it possible to get the tables one after the other? Then naming them 1(a) and 1(b) both different captions. They show related data but there is a difference in the method, which explains my need.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora I updated my answer.